# hospital search on mapkit search

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

i want to search for different hospitals near to my location and then show them on map. But the problem is i don't know how to search for hospitals near to my location. Any help about searching the location for hospital is appreciated.

Comment: I also used mapKit to locate hotels and I am passing name of hotel.But it is searching only famous place not all.So this is not necessary that it will search hospital.

Comment: how u use mapkit to locate hotels near to your location and sample code or guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the Google maps API to do a similar thing. Have a look at the documentation here;-

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches

You'll need to get an API key as well as accept the terms and conditions but as you are using MapKit, you are effectively doing this anyway. This is mentioned in Apple's documentation.

One other alternative would be to use Foursquare data as they too have an API and the data quality *should* be reasonably good. However, that will be another API, terms etc. to deal with and it might be more fiddly to filter your search to just hospitals.

Once you have some results and parse them, MapKit has a very straightforward API for adding the annotations to the map.

Answer (score 3):

You can query GeoNames' [webservices](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html): [this example](http://api.geonames.org/search?q=london&maxRows=10&featureClass=S&featureCode=HSP&username=demo) searches for hospitals near London.

Beware that GeoNames' results are not foolproof, and they don't offer any guarantee on data accuracy. Do not use it for emergency situations.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Google Places API](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)

Answer (score 3):

you can use mapkit
[MapKit Tutorial](http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial)

Comment: the problem is not showing them on map the problem is how to get data of hospital with their coordinate and name

Comment: The problem is getting data of all the hospitals how to get them and from where. The different application at app store from they get data.

Comment: It is note possible to get data from map Api. you have to create your own database either save it locally or call it from web service. Map Api will show its location only

Comment: ok..and if you find any way to get data..then please tell me also.:)

Comment: okay sure, but seems impossible